# how to select a group in r dataframe if all units passed

Tags: r

I want to select a group and paste into new dataframe if all units in group are under 5V. how can I do so in r?

sample dataframe

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work, you can assign below output to a new dataframe:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(GroupID) %>% filter(all(Voltage < 5))
# A tibble: 4 x 2
# Groups:   GroupID [1]
  GroupID Voltage
    <dbl>   <dbl>
1       2    3.12
2       2    3.24
3       2    3.21
4       2    3.19
```

Data used:

```
df
  GroupID Voltage
1       1    3.11
2       1    3.21
3       1    5.01
4       1    3.19
5       2    3.12
6       2    3.24
7       2    3.21
8       2    3.19
```

Answer (score 1):

Using base R you can do this with the help of `ave` :

```
df1 <- subset(df, ave(Voltage < 5, GroupID, FUN = all))
df1

#  GroupID Voltage
#5       2    3.12
#6       2    3.24
#7       2    3.21
#8       2    3.19
```

and in `data.table` :

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[all(Voltage < 5)], GroupID]
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(GroupID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
Voltage = c(3.11, 3.21, 5.01, 3.19, 3.12, 3.24, 3.21, 3.19)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```